# Display custom product attribute value in WooCommerce product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

I will be adding custom product attributes to the product data for products in my woocommerce catalogue.

How can I fetch the values of this field to display in the product page/template?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following using `WC_Product` `get_attribute()` method:

```
global $product; // if the WC_Product object is not defined

if ( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
}

echo  '<p>' . $product->get_attribute( 'secimg' ) . '</p>';
```

Its should work.